# What is this options bar in PhpStorm called?

Tags: phpstorm

I have this weird bar that shows up on some of the pages that I am working on in PhpStorm that is really annoying, as it often blocks what I am trying to work on. I can't move it or remove it. Does anyone know what it is and how to get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This floating toolbar appears in Markdown files (not sure about any other file types, at very least I see it only there).

I see 3 icons only (in current stable PhpStorm **2022.2.3 version**), which may depend on the features used (e.g. I have Diagrams plugin disabled):

[image]

1. Text only mode
2. Split mode: text + rendered preview
3. Rendered mode only (HTML preview)

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/markdown.html#preview

The other 2 icons visible on your screen **MIGHT be for**:

- Visualizing diagrams for the Mermaid and PlantUML languages (*I do not have them in any of my files so cannot check it. But it should be that*).
  [image]
  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/markdown.html#diagrams
- Pandoc Converter for HTML, Microsoft Word, and PDF formats (*not using it myself*).
  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/markdown.html#convert-markdown-files

---

> ...it often blocks what I am trying to work on. I can't move it or remove it. Does anyone know what it is and how to get rid of it?

- It is displayed in the top right corner where it is hard to cover anything.
- I see no options anywhere to remove it. But you can "convert" it into the permanently visible toolbar instead if you prefer:

1. `Help | Find Action...`
2. Type `registry` to locate and invoke `Registry...` entry.
3. Once in the Registry, locate `ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar` entry there (just start typing, the speed search works there)
   [image]
4. Disable it (make sure it's saved) and restart the IDE. Now it will look like this (a fixed bar instead of "annoying floating" one):
   [image]